# Boto3 - Describe Redshift

Tags: json, boto3

I have the following code, but it throws error:

```
import boto3
import json
import string

client = boto3.client('redshift', 'us-east-1')
cluster_list = client.describe_clusters()

result = [{"{#REDSHIFT}": row['Clusters'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']} for row in client.describe_clusters()]
result = {"data": result}
json_pre = json.dumps(result)
json_pos = json_pre.translate(None, string.whitespace)
print json_pos
```

But I have the following error:

line 8, in

```
result = [{"{#REDSHIFT}": row['Clusters'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']} for row in client.describe_clusters()]
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I would like to return the values of `['Clusters'][0]['Endpoint']['Address']` to generate a Json.

Answer (score 0):

The correct code is here:

```
import boto3
import json
import string

client = boto3.client('redshift', 'us-east-1')
cluster_list = client.describe_clusters()

result = [{"{#REDSHIFT}": red['Endpoint']['Address']} for red in cluster_list['Clusters']]
result = {"data": result}
json_pre = json.dumps(result)
json_pos = json_pre.translate(None, string.whitespace)
print json_pos
```